# Microsoft ReportViewer not rendering on server

Tags: iis-7, reportviewer

I have a reportviewer control that works fine locally, but when deployed to the IIS 7 webserver, it just returns a blank page (or XML error in Firefox).

I thought it was permission related but I've given everyone permission as a Hail Mary and still I get a blank report with typically sparse MS error handling to help me track down the issue.

Has anyone else run into this?

Using IIS 7 and ReportViewer 9.0

Comment: OK, new info:

If I switch the applicationpool back to CLASSIC then everything starts working.  However, in INTEGRATED mode, I get blank rendering of all reportviewer controls.

Comment: take look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx. It shows how to run in integrated mode for IIS 7.

Comment: Yup, I've got the new <handlers> section under <system.webserver> but it still renders blank in anything but classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your using IIS 6 for development and IIS 7 for deployment. IIS7 it might be using integrated pipeline. In that case

```
<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

will not fire and nothing is rendered. Either you switch to classic pipeline or update your web.config. HttpHandler have a different section in web.config for intregrated pipeline.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx

Comment: I've tried all those things, and under integrated mode the reportviewer will not load.

I've added the handler to the <system.webServer><handlers> tag but only in integrated mode nothing will render.

Answer (score 0):

I added the name attribute to the what Fahad posted and this worked great. Thanks! I can now use my MVC project with a ReportViewerControl on a WebForms page. Exactly what I needed.

```
<add verb="*" name="ReportViewerWebControl" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```